# Vector pop_back() removing more than 1 entry

Tags: c++

I have a simple function that loops while there are still elements in a vector. Inside the loop, a single element is popped from the end of the vector using pop_back(). For some reason my code is removing 2 elements every time this is called.

```
vector<Vertex> vertices;

while ( vertices.size() != 0 ) {
    std::cerr << "We are in the loop, size: " << vertices.size() << std::endl;
    Vertex tmp = vertices.back();
    // do stuff with tmp, not shown here;  
    vertices.pop_back();
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
We are in the loop, size: 3
We are in the loop, size: 1
```

To clarify, this is the output of the exact code above.

EDIT:

```
vector<Vertex> vertices;

while ( vertices.size() != 0 ) {

    Vertex tmp = vertices.back();
    std::cerr << "We are in the loop, size: " << vertices.size() << std::endl;
    vertices.pop_back();
    std::cerr << "We are in the loop, size: " << vertices.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
We are in the loop, size: 3
We are in the loop, size: 1
We are in the loop, size: 1
We are in the loop, size: 0
```

EDIT 2:

I changed my implementation from vector to deque. Using the exact same commands I've managed to achieve the desired output:

```
We are in the loop, size: 3 
We are in the loop, size: 2 
We are in the loop, size: 2 
We are in the loop, size: 1 
We are in the loop, size: 1 
We are in the loop, size: 0
```

Still can't explain the behaviour from before; thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: $100 the error is "not shown here". Also, always use `!empty()` as opposed to `size() != 0`.

Comment: Print out the size just before the pop.  You're probably accidentally popping/removing an element somewhere else in the omitted code.

Comment: Is the size what you expect just before the `pop_back()` call?

Comment: What is in the "now shown here" section ?

Comment: http://codepad.org/UmARn3qR <-- Status no-repro

Comment: *"this is the output of the exact code above"* - It can't be the exact output of that code, because `vertices` is empty. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I've searched my entire program and can verify pop_back() is not being called anywhere else.

Comment: @CallMeRex - there are other ways of removing items from a vector *and* if you've overflowed the vector by using `operator[]` to access something after the end then you'll see weirdness

Comment: There is no way your code can produce that output. Something is missing.

Comment: @juanchopanza I don't disagree with you, the only other place I'm currently referencing vertices is when I add 3 Vertex objects using vertices.push_back(). This function also verifies that I have 3 Vertex objects in vertices before I run the code above.

Comment: We need a small compilable example that reproduces the problem. The act of creating a small compilable example will probably allow you to stumble across the error in another part of your code.

Comment: @Loki, I'll take your advice; thank you.

Comment: I changed my implementation from vector to deque. Using the exact same commands I've managed to achieve the desired output: We are in the loop, size: 3
We are in the loop, size: 2
We are in the loop, size: 2
We are in the loop, size: 1
We are in the loop, size: 1
We are in the loop, size: 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Kerrek SB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596781/kerrek-sb) mentioned error is not in the code given, I tried following code and it works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main ( int argc, char **argv) {
    std::vector<int> v;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        v.push_back(i);
    }
    while ( !v.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "We are in the loop, size: " << v.size() << std::endl;
        int tmp = v.back();
        v.pop_back();
    }
}
```